# NextJS 9 / Apollo Routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js, react-apollo

I'm new to Next.JS and Apollo and have been using them to create a personal website.

I'm encountering issues with Routing between pages - or passing the correct ID from the homepage and main blog page to the actual post to query and render all the content.

I use a similar query on both pages; the difference on the homepage is it's minus the main post content.

NextJS correctly routes to the page given the query parameter I pass (the title) but I'm unable to render the rest of the content -- given the other page query doesn't have the ID for calling.

How am I supposed to combine Next.JS routing and Apollo to correctly pass data between both places?

Any help explaining this would be greatly appreciated; I'd like to know how it's done so I can work through this problem myself in the future.

Here's the code for the homepage component:

```
const getArticles = gql`
    {
        articles(limit: 3) {
            id
            coverImg {
                id
                url
            }
            title
            date
            excerpt
            user{
                name
            }
        }
    }
`;

const Articles = () =>
{
    const { data, error, loading } = useQuery( getArticles );
    if ( loading )
    {
        return <Load />;
    }
    if ( error )
    {
        return <div>
            <Err/>
            Error! { error.message }</div>;
    }

    return (
        <div className={ s.recentArticles }>
            { data.articles.map( article => (
                <Post
                    type='post'
                    key={ article.id }
                    coverImg={ article.coverImg.url }
                    title={ article.title }
                    date={ article.date }
                    name={ article.user.name }
                    excerpt={ article.excerpt }
                />
            ) ) }
        </div>
    );

};
export default () => <Articles />;
```

And the Actual Post Content

```
const getArticle = gql`
    {
        article (id:id) {
            id
            coverImg {
                id
                url
            }
            title
            updated_at
            content
            user{
                name
            }
            tags
        }
    }
`;

const Post = () =>
{

    const { data, error, loading } = useQuery( getArticle );
    if ( loading )
    {
        return <Load/>;
    }
    if ( error )
    {
        return <div>
            <Err/>
            Error! { error.message }</div>;
    }

    return (
        <main className={s.post}>
            <Nav />
            <CoverImg title={data.article.title} url={data.article.coverImg.url}/>
            <Tags />
            <Body content={data.article.content}/>
            <Sidebar />
            <Footer />
        </main>
    );
};
export default () => <Post />;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the ID. I have refactored your post content below

```js
const getArticle = gql`
   query getArticle($id: ID!) {
        article (id: $id) {
            id
            coverImg {
                id
                url
            }
            title
            updated_at
            content
            user{
                name
            }
            tags
        }
    }
`;

const Post = ({articleId}) =>
{

    const { data, error, loading } = useQuery( getArticle, { variables: { id } } );
    if ( loading )
    {
        return <Load/>;
    }
    if ( error )
    {
        return <div>
            <Err/>
            Error! { error.message }</div>;
    }

    return (
        <main className={s.post}>
            <Nav />
            <CoverImg title={data.article.title} url={data.article.coverImg.url}/>
            <Tags />
            <Body content={data.article.content}/>
            <Sidebar />
            <Footer />
        </main>
    );
};
export default () => <Post />;
```

Note the **dollar** sign in front of the id prop and the query name.

```
 query getArticle($id: ID!) {
        article (id: $id) {
```

Also note the **variables** option

```js
useQuery(getArticle, { variables: { id: articleId } });
```

Also note the `articleId` prop being used. To get that, you need to change the article list component as below:

```
 <Post
      type='post'
      key={ article.id }
      articleId={ article.id }
      coverImg={ article.coverImg.url }
      title={ article.title
      date={ article.date }
      name={ article.user.name }
      excerpt={ article.excerpt }
/>
```

NOTE: React does not pass through the `key` property, so that can't be used inside the component